# Multicolor Complication Text

Tags: swift, clockkit, watchos-5

I am creating a `.graphicCorner` ClockKit complication using the template `CLKComplicationTemplateGraphicCornerTextImage`. As mentioned in the Tech Talk [Developing Complications for Apple Watch Series 4](https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/tech-talks/208/) it should be possible to combine multiple differently tinted Text Providers.

Unfortunately I can make it work.

Here's my code from `ComplicationController.swift`

```
func getLocalizableSampleTemplate(for complication: CLKComplication, withHandler handler: @escaping (CLKComplicationTemplate?) -> Void) {
    switch complication.family {
…
    case .graphicCorner:
        if #available(watchOSApplicationExtension 5.0, *) {
            let template = CLKComplicationTemplateGraphicCornerStackText()
            let firstTextProvider = CLKSimpleTextProvider(text: "first")
            firstTextProvider.tintColor = UIColor.green
            let secondTextProvider = CLKSimpleTextProvider(text: "second")
            secondTextProvider.tintColor = UIColor.red
            let thirdTextProvider = CLKSimpleTextProvider(text: "third")
            thirdTextProvider.tintColor = UIColor.blue
            template.outerTextProvider = firstTextProvider
            template.innerTextProvider = CLKTextProvider.localizableTextProvider(withStringsFileFormatKey: "STRINGFORMAT", textProviders: [secondTextProvider, thirdTextProvider])
            handler(template)
        } else {
            handler(nil)  // Fallback on earlier versions
        }

    default:
        handler(nil)
    }

}
```

and the content of my `ckcomplication.strings`

```
"STRINGFORMAT" = "%@ %@";
```

No text will show up. What am I doing wrong here? I appreciate any idea or working examples.

Comment: Does it show if you don't set `tintColor` in your providers? The localizable text provider might not support multiple colors.

Comment: @Bernd I am running into the same problem here. Have you been able to resolve this yet?

Answer (score 1):

This seems to be the expected behaviour, at least for `outerTextProvider`:

> The complication ignores the text provider’s tint color. It always displays the outer text as white.

[outerTextProvider](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/clockkit/clkcomplicationtemplategraphiccornerstacktext/3026284-outertextprovider)

It works for the innerTextProvider though, at least in here:

```
case .graphicCorner:
                let graphicCorner = CLKComplicationTemplateGraphicCornerStackText()
                let metarColor = UIColor.green
                graphicCorner.outerTextProvider = CLKSimpleTextProvider(text: "EGLL")
                    graphicCorner.innerTextProvider = CLKSimpleTextProvider(text: "MVFR 27' ago")
                    graphicCorner.innerTextProvider.tintColor = metarColor ?? UIColor.white
                    let entry = CLKComplicationTimelineEntry(date: NSDate( as Date, complicationTemplate : graphicCorner)
                    timelineEntries.append(entry)
```

[Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xyI2G.png)

Answer (score 0):

I ran into the same problem. I couldn't get `CLKTextProvider.localizableTextProvider(withStringsFileFormatKey:, textProviders: )` combined with a `ckcomplication.strings` to work.

I ended up using [this Objective-C category](https://gist.github.com/SlaunchaMan/815b3e7214ceb2000e64) on `CLKTextProvider`.

It needed little customization for my own needs, but other than that it seems to work for me, I now get multi-coloured text in the inner ring.